# Why doesn't the context menu work in the "Notepad" tutorial?

Tags: android

I'm working through the 'notepad' tutorial given in the developer's guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/notepad/index.html

For some reason, even when i'm using their solution files, the context menu does not come up with i 'click and hold' on a list entry.

The class extends ListActivity, and calls "registerForContextMenu(getListView());"

but I never see the context menu fire.

Any idea what's wrong with it?

Comment: Is this on your phone or emulator? What happens when you do long press? What does it say in adb logcat when you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way they lay out the rows in that tutorial means that you can only actually make a selection on text, not just the row it's on. Are you pressing on the row itself?

You can fix that by using fill_parent instead of wrap_content in the layout_width attributes of the LinearLayout and ListView in notes_list.xml, and in the TextView inside notes_row.xml

Comment: Wow, you're right!
I tried to click that a million times, but I guess short text lengths + touch screen == nearly impossible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to click the menu to bring up the 'Add Item' option.

If you're using the emulator, the menu is the icon on the bottom left that looks like a 2X3 array.